# Как убрать запятую после split и как сделать несколько разделителей?

Tags: javascript

Как убрать запятую после split и как сделать несколько разделителей? Например так `split('.mp3','.ogg','.wav')`

```
var tags = "audio.mp3";
alert(tags.split('.mp3'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение `/\.(?:mp3|ogg|wav)/` и метод `filter()`:

```js
var tags = "audio.mp3";
var delim = /\.(?:mp3|ogg|wav)/;
var isNotEmpty = function(v){ return v && v.length };
alert(tags.split(delim).filter(isNotEmpty));
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, работает!